# Process Being Killed due to low swap

Tags: osx, python, memory, swap

I'm running a python (2.7) script on mac osx yosemite.

The script is fairly computationally intensive, certainly bumping up against my machine's RAM limitations. The computer crashes and restarts midway through executing the script. The system logs in `/var/log/system.log` contain messages suggesting that this is due to running out of swap space.

`kernel[0]: low swap: killing pid 1246 (mdworker)`

... (a few more such messages for different mdworker processes)

`kernel[0]: low swap: unable to find any eligible processes to take action on`

... (it says this a few dozen times in the hour leading up to the crash)

`kernel[0]: low swap: killing pid 1711 (mdworker)`

How can I prevent this crash?

Comment: Consider is the amount of memory that the process uses bounded. Is the memory used in a stack like way, not too much random access. If so then try adding more swap. This will need space on the secondary storage device (hard disk).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't prevent this crash, if you don't change operating system or computer(related to memory) on which you executed your program(mdworker).

In practice, allocatable memory is equal to `RAM+(SWAP SPACE)`, but I guess that your program, mdworker, is over limitation `(RAM+SWAP SPACE)`.

Did you allocate too large data(array, etc...)?

Comment: mdworker is from Apple. The kernel is not able to find the culprit and start to kill possible problematic processes (and kills mdworker).